# Single code coverage file for multiple test cases in MTM

Tags: code-coverage, microsoft-test-manager, mtm

I have been assigned to configure code coverage in MTM. I made all the settings and I was able to get it successful.

But one of our requirement says that we need to have single code coverage file for suite / multiple test case execution.

I tried executing multiple test cases by selecting with control key, after executing the test case I'm getting code coverage file for each test case.

For Example: 2 .coverage file for 2 test cases.

Is there any way to have single .coverage file for multiple test cases execution?